# Python reference to object to save extra typing

Tags: python, pointers, reference, alias

How can I alias/reference/point an object with a very long name in order to save extra typing in Python?

I would like something working similarly to the following C++ code:

```
//example of a complex type, here it can be a class with an attribute 
//which is a map, mapping a string to two nested struct
string * alias = &(very_long_variable_name.I_do_not["want"].to_carry_with.me);

if(*alias == "hey" || *alias == "hi") {
    *alias = "I saved a lot of typing!";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate elements of a `bytearray` when two variables are pointing to it:

```
s = "Hello World!"

b = bytearray(s.encode('utf-8'))
a = b

print(b)

b[0]=ord('C')

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
bytearray(b'Hello World!')
bytearray(b'Cello World!')
bytearray(b'Cello World!')
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, when you do

```
 very_long_object_name_in_python = SomeClass()
 short_name = very_long_object_name_in_python

 print(id(very_long_object_name_in_python))
 print(id(short_name))
```

You have the same output, that mean they reference to the same object.

You can see it in this image from python-tutor website that both aliases hold reference to the same instance of the class.

[image]

**UPDATE**: but this does not hold true for strings, when you do this assignment python does a copy of the string and save the reference in the new var.

[image]

Comment: It **does not** work, it is the same output but if you then do `short_name = something` then the two ids change and the original variable is untouched

Comment: Yes, that works only with inplace operations like .append()  or comparison, like your example

Comment: The object I am pointing to is a string, how can I change its value?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python :-( You can always have an intermediate object which holds the string. Or you can use a **bytearray**

Comment: @quamrana I do not know how to use them, what would my code look like?